# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, " M397,NaN L397,0 A0,0,…"

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, floor, math-functions

i have this error when I try to put a value in the field radius and innerRadius value (in a Solid Gauge, amchart)

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, " M397,NaN L397,0 A0,0,…".

I tried to find some topic with the error in common this but i didin't found anything.

The two functions that i use for found the value are:

```
"radius": ( 5 + ( Math.floor( index / 2 ) * ( 100 / length ) ) ) + "%",
"innerRadius": ( ( Math.floor( index / 2 ) + 1 ) * ( 100 / length ) ) + "%"
```

The problem is using this function

```
"radius": (105 - ( Math.floor ( index / 2 ) * length ) ) + "%",
"innerRadius": ( 100 - ( Math.floor ( index / 2 ) * length ) ) + "%"
```

The error is not shown.

Comment: Check the values of `index` and `length` with a debugger (or `console.log`), to begin with.

Comment: the values are corrects. I already debug wih console.log

Comment: Let me rephrase my doubt: the only sensible difference, mathematically speaking, is that the first example contains a division by `length`, the second doesn't. So, are you sure that `length` is never 0?

Comment: I make some console.log for be sure and at the beginning the length is null but the error arrives after the change of the value (because the length changes dynamically). Also i tried to set the value > 0 and it has the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I found the error. The error is when i set radius and innerRadius value with the "%". I tried to use toFixed method too, it works without errors

```
"innerRadius":  ( ( Math.floor( index / 2 ) + 1 ) * ( 100 / length ) ).toFixed(2) + "%" ,
```

but when i add ' + "%" ' give me the error path. But before it works perfectly, or with others formula. Also i tried to use toString() methods too but it didn't work.